# session issue in function.php WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am new to WordPress. I have code of PayPal `IPN` in `function.php`. I create one hook for that. Now my question is that I didn't receive session value in this hook. I tried every options like

1. Do code in `wp-config.php` (`session_start()`)
2. Do code in `wp-settings.php` (`$noUnset = array('GLOBALS', '_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE', '_REQUEST', '_SERVER', '_ENV', '_FILES', 'table_prefix', '_SESSION');`)
3. also start session in both files (in my hook and other file)
4. Also tried plugin for session.
5. Also done code in `function.php` 
              (

   ```
           if (!session_id()) {
              session_start();
           }

           function sess_start() { 
             if (!session_id()) 
               session_start(); 
           } 
           add_action('init','sess_start');

          )
   ```

this is my code:

```
 add_action('paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_payment_status_completed', 'process_payment', 10, 1);
 function process_payment( $posted )
 { 
   if( !session_id())
    session_start();

$email12 = $_SESSION['email12'];   
// Parse data from IPN $posted[] array
$first_name = isset($posted['first_name']) ? $posted['first_name'] : '';
$last_name = isset($posted['last_name']) ? $posted['last_name'] : '';
$payment_amount = isset($posted['mc_gross']) ? $posted['mc_gross'] : '';
$recurring_payment_id = isset($posted['recurring_payment_id']) ? $posted['recurring_payment_id'] : '';
$payer_email = isset($posted['payer_email']) ? $posted['payer_email'] : '';
$txn_id = isset($posted['txn_id']) ? $posted['txn_id'] : '';
$receiver_email= isset($posted['receiver_email']) ? $posted['receiver_email'] : '';   
    $mail_From    = $payer_email;
    $mail_To      = $receiver_email;
    $mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
    $mail_Body    = "Hello Secretary,
                 New registration for the event: 
                     Name: $first_name $last_name";
 mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);   
    $mail_From    = $receiver_email;
    $mail_To      = $payer_email;
    $mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
    $mail_Body    = "Thank you for registration. Your registration has been successfully done.";
mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);       
 global $wpdb; 
     $id12 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_tmpnonmembersdetail");

    foreach($id12 as $row1)
 {
$wpdb->insert( wp_checkoutnonmembersdetails, array( 
                            'Event_Name' => $row1->Event_Name,
                            'Event_Date' => $row1->date,
            'First_Name' => $row1->First_Name,
            'Last_Name' => $row1->Last_Name, 
            'Address' => $row1->Address, 
            'Email' => $email12  , 
            'cellphone' => $row1->cellphone, 
            'quantity' => $row1->quantity,
                            'reg_date' => $row1->date,
                            'payment_amount' => $payment_amount
    ) );
  }


$id22 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_tmpmembersdetail where  id = '$id1' ");
foreach($id22 as $row2)
{
$wpdb->insert( wp_checkouttmpmembersdetail, array( 
                            'Event_Name' => $row2->Event_Name,
            'First_Name' => $row2->First_Name,
            'Last_Name' => $row2->Last_Name, 
            'Address' => $row2->Address, 
            'Email' => $row2->Email, 
            'cellphone' => $row2->cellphone, 
            'quantity' => $row2->quantity,
                            'payment_amount' => $payment_amount
    ) );
    } 
  }
```

And another strange thing is that I got another session in same `function.php` file in other hook.
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting exactly the problem of session. However, 2 things I would like to ask

1. In which page or function are you creating these 3 sessions ($_SESSION['email']) ?
2. in following code you wrote wrong variable name - I guess it should be $email and NOT $email12

   ```
   $id12 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM table_name where Email= '$email12'  ");
   ```

$_SESSION variable values can only be retrieved once it has been created. If you have written this code manually you must have written /creating these $_SESSION vars.

If it is plugin and you do not know from where you will get - try searching `$_SESSION['email'] =`  code or text in the plugin files.

Comment: In, php files I am creating those 3 sessions, and $email12 was my writing mistake.

Comment: try to create simple php files to test out whether SESSION VARS works on your server or not. create 2 custom php file - in one file create a session and in another file try to retrieve the value of that session.

Comment: ya we retrieve value of that session in another file. but we did not getting value of the same session in function.php file.

Comment: right this code on top of the function.php file -

if (!isset($_SESSION))
{
   session_start();
}

Comment: can u email me login so that i can check?